# Livereload NoMethodError

Tags: livereload

when trying to compile a sass file, I get this error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Anyone can help?

LiveReload : 2.3.5
Mac OS : 10.9.1

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have run into the same issue and am not sure how to fix it!

Comment: No. I updated Xcode but the error still here.

Comment: Hmmm frustrating because it looks so promising. I am having the exact same issue with the latest version of XCode & CLT. I am actually running LiveReload 2.3.8 so clearly not something that was fixed if it is an issue with LiveReload.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that I have tested using Prepros and it works perfectly (although I would prefer to be able to use LiveReload)!